# Crystal Report, C# Decimal Rounding Not Same

Tags: c#, excel, crystal-reports

I don't know if this is crystal report problem or C#.

In Crystal Report, `ROUND(0.0625, 3)` will give `0,063`

In C#, `Math.Round(0.0625, 3)` will give `0,062`

I tried in Excel, `ROUND(0.0625, 3)` will give `0,063`

I tried in SQL Server, `SELECT ROUND(0.0625, 3)` will give `0,063`

I don't know which one is true and this is make a big problem now because the result in my excel report and crystal report not same with calculated database.

Comment: By "In C#, ROUND(0.0625, 3) will give 0,062" to you mean calling `Math.Round`? Or something else? Note that there's an overload for `Math.Round` excepting a `MidpointRounding` enum value, which is probably what you want to do here.

Comment: In C#, `Math.Round(0.0625, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` will give you 0.063.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it is `Math.Round()`, Wait, I will give it a try

Comment: Thank you very much, this is solve the problem now. I must change all round with that now.